# Firefox, touchpad middle-button, open in new tab, lenovo T60

Tags: firefox, touchpad, thinkpad

I use Firefox 18.0 with Xubuntu 12.04 on a lenovo Laptop T60.

I like to use the middle button above the touchpad to do a middle-click on a link to open that page in a new tab. It works with the mouse and it worked with my former laptop, a Thinkpad T41 with very similar touchpad.

I can open a link in a new tab too if I hit the left and right button meanwhile, but that's not comfortable.

I find this with synclient:

```
synclient -l
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1752
    RightEdge               = 5192
    TopEdge                 = 1620
    BottomEdge              = 4236
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    FingerPress             = 256
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 221
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    FastTaps                = 0
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 100
    HorizScrollDelta        = 100
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 1
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0398089
    TrackstickSpeed         = 40
    EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
    EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
    EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
    EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 401
    EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 25
    VertHysteresis          = 25
    ClickPad                = 0
```

I guess LTRB stands for left, top, right, bottom - MT for middle-top is missing.

Btw: Middle Click for pasting works. I'm curious how that fits together.

Comment: You need to look at the `synclient -l` output. Assigning to a button the value of '2' usually does the new tab trick.

Comment: Not a real answer, but if it is only for opening a link in a new tab the just use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>, whis is easily done with one hand on the T60 :-))

Comment: @guntbert I don't know how the "middle button above the touchpad" is idefined by synclient, so that would have been a vague anser indeed.

Comment: @mikewhatever: I updated the question. Where would I do the assignment? There is no xorg.conf any more.

Comment: It works and is a new information for me, but not an answer to my question.

Comment: Thank you for that output, but you should probably post all of it without grepping. Those Thinkpads have so many buttons, it's mind blowing.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Here we have 69 rows.

Comment: Can you verify in `about:config` in Firefox that `browser.tabs.opentabfor.middleclick` is set to true? Have you tried a clean Firefox profile? (e.g. starting `firefox -safe-mode -P <profile>`) What happens in for example Chrome? (should work by default) And have you tried this in the Guest user (or another user account) to exclude any user-specific mouse settings?

Comment: @userunknown Thanks. To be honest, i've no idea how those buttons above the touchpad are defined, or what they do. They are ThinkPad unique, and I've never had one. What does that MidButton do? LTRB, LTRT, etc are pretty standard, and stand for the touchpad corners. As defined in your case, tapping in the top-right corner will open links in new tabs (Firefox, Nautilus) `RTCornerButton = 2`, and tapping in the right-bottom corner should emulate a right-click - `RBCornerButton = 3`.

Comment: @gertvdijk: I've done none of these things, and please note, that it works as expected for the real mouse. I don't think that firefox has a distinction for mouse/touchpad.

Comment: @userunknown Okay, I overlooked the mouse part in your question. I've owned a T61 and the middle button behaved the same way as the middle button on my Logitech mouse. The same as in that Xorg doesn't see any distinction.

Comment: @gertvdijk:, mikewhatever: I'm sorry, but while experimenting, I found my fault: I asked myself "what does the middle button do at all, if not opening a new tab?" and the surprising answer was: Nothing at all. But why does pasting maked text work? Because I have a different hit technik for that cases: Shorter and harder clicks. Seems to be a hardware problem. If I hit the button hard and short enough, it opens links in new tabs. I'm sorry and I guess I should close and delete my question then, instead of giving a self-answer?

Comment: gertvdijk, @mikewhatever:  It's a hardware thing, and probably too localized (except the middle button is often a problem on some thinkpads. It is a refurbished model - not new, just new for me).

Comment: Provide an answer yourself. Might be useful for others having the same hardware issue lost in Ubuntu though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but while experimenting, I found it to be my own fault: I asked myself

- "what does the middle button do at all, if not opening a new tab?" and the surprising answer was: Nothing at all.
- But why does pasting maked text work? Because I have a different hit technik for that cases: Shorter and harder clicks.

Seems to be a **hardware problem**. If I hit the button hard and short enough, it opens links in new tabs. I'm sorry and provide a self-answer, if maybe this hardware problem is not too rare. Since refurbished Thinkpads are quite common, it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Middle button on a ThinkPad has two modes of action: `middle click` and `scroll with trackpoint`.

Clicking middle button quickly causes a middle click action while holding it down and using the trackpoint allows you to scroll whatever is under the cursor.

This is a hardware feature and requires no support from OS.

Comment: Oh, yes, that works. However, hitting the middle button depends on luck and I often need several trials.

Comment: That is odd. From my experience the threshold for scrolling is around 200ms or so and any click faster than that is a middle click.